# Dynamically Get Size of Files in Amazon S3 Bucket

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I've seen previous questions on "How to find the size of an entire S3 bucket."  This is somewhat of a different question-- so I apologize in advance if it is vague.  I'll do my best to explain what I am trying to achieve.

I am currently using [Amazon S3 PHP Class](http://undesigned.org.za/2007/10/22/amazon-s3-php-class).

This is what I am trying to achieve:

1. I would like to be able to loop through my MySQL database and get specific filenames of files on my S3 server. (This may be based on user).
2. During the loop, query the Amazon S3 bucket (somehow) and get the filesize of each file that was in my MySQL loop.
3. Add up all the filesizes, to get one total approximate bytesize.

So, essentially, let's say I have a user that has 5 files on the S3 bucket.  How might I be able to query the S3 bucket, to see how much data this user's 5 files is storing in my bucket?

My apologies if this is difficult to understand.  I can re-articulate, if needed.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You really should be storing the filesize in your Mysql table.  Faster to get the info, less S3 cost.

But... try this?

```php
$s3 = new Aws\S3\S3Client($parameters);
$obj_data = $s3->headObject([
   'Bucket' => $bucket,
   'Key'    => $key
]);
echo 'Size is: '.$obj_data['ContentLength'];
```

Comment: Upvote for "You really should be storing the filesize in your Mysql table"

Comment: there is no `getObjectInfo` method in php aws sdk.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/api/class-Aws.S3.S3Client.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/class-Aws.S3.S3Client.html

Answer (score 7):

Now that AWS has released a support PHP SDK, you might want to consider looking into switching to use that: http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforphp/.

It also includes api for getting an object size: get_object_filesize().

I agree with John Ventimiglia.  Each call to S3 take time and costs money.  If you can store the information locally, it will provide a better customer experience (faster) and be cheaper.

Comment: I wasn't aware of the AWS PHP SDK.  I'll have to play around with it.  You're both right about storing the information.  I'm in the process of locally storing the filesizes.  Many thanks.

Answer (score 5):

In 2015 I have to use http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/guide/feature-s3-stream-wrapper.html for that

```
$client->registerStreamWrapper();
```

and then

```
$size = filesize('s3://' . $bucket . '/' . $key);
```

I hope that will helps to someone.

Answer (score 3):

Addition to [chrisjmccreadie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1693491/chrisjmccreadie) answer.

The method [`list_objects('')`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSDKforPHP/latest/index.html#m=AmazonS3/list_objects) is paginated which may not provide results more than 1000, as the default is 1000, so you will need to go through pagination for complete accurate results.

But you can use [`get_object_list()`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSDKforPHP/latest/index.html#m=AmazonS3/get_object_list) method which will return `max-keys` result.

include("sdk.class.php");

```
    $s3 = new AmazonS3();

    $response = $s3->get_object_list('mojag');
    foreach ($response->body as $object)
    {
        //print_r($object);
        echo $object->Key.'('.$object->Size.')</br>';
        $size  = $size+$object->Size;

    }
    $size = number_format($size / 1024 / 1024, 2); 

    echo $size;
```

Answer (score 1):

I do store in my MYSQL but sometime you need to do clean up and it is good to know any mismatch between your MSYQL and S3.  When I need to get the file size I list all the files and count the file size

```
include("sdk.class.php");

        $s3 = new AmazonS3();

        $response = $s3->list_objects('mojag');
        foreach ($response->body as $object)
        {
            //print_r($object);
            echo $object->Key.'('.$object->Size.')</br>';
            $size  = $size+$object->Size;

        }
        $size = number_format($size / 1024 / 1024, 2); 

        echo $size;
```